# What is the most efficient way to select sorted data based on many-to-many relation and also select all related to it data

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, i have this postgreSQL database structure

### posts

id
title
text

### tags

id
name

### posts_tags

post_id
tag_id

So, one post could have many tags and one tag could have many stories.
What i wanna do is to query database and get all posts that has a certain tag.
And i could do this with something like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.name = 'my_tag'
```

But i want to also select ALL tags attached to each post, now i could do something like

```
SELECT p.*, t.name` FROM posts p ...
```

instead of what i did above, but it would only give me the name of one tag, while i need to get all.
What is the most efficient peformance-wise way to do it?
And how to do the same, but selecting only the posts that contain multiple specified tags?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Okay, lets assume we have 3 posts and 10 tags(which are different from each other). Post1 has tag3, tag5, tag7 and tag9, post2 has tag1, tag3, tag5, post3 has tag2, tag3, tag10. I want to select all posts and all its tags, that for example have tag3 and tag5 on them. So, in this example i would expect to get post1 and post2, but not post3, because post3 doesnt have tag5 on it. And on selected posts(post1 and post2) i would expect to have a column that would have all the tags names or ids for each post on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method might be aggregation:

```
SELECT p.*, ARRAY_AGG(t.name) as tags
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     posts_tags pt
     ON pt.post_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     tags t
     ON pt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING bool_or(t.name = 'my_tag');
```

The `bool_or()` is saying that one of the tags is the one you are looking for.

Comment: that worked, but can i use it to find posts that contain multiple tags? Like filter posts to only thouse that have tag1 and tag2? Do i just use something like `HAVING bool_or(t.name = 'tag1') AND bool_or(t.name = 'tag2')`? Or there is a better way? I'm realy knew to all this stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the post along with other tags like following.

```
SELECT p.*,t.* FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
INNER JOIN
(
    select post_id from posts_tags pt1
    inner join tags t on pt1.tag_id=t.id
    where t.name='my_tag'
    group by post_id
) t on t.post_id=p.id
```

You can also get it using  `EXISTS` like following.

```
SELECT p.*,t.* FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE EXISTS
(
    select 1 from posts_tags pt1
    inner join tags t on pt1.tag_id=t.id
    where t.name='my_tag' and pt1.postid=p.id
)
```